# Migrating Wordpress to a new server stops thumbnails and galleries working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, web-hosting

I migrated from one host to another and copied across my Wordpress installations. No problems, I've done this before. But on two of my three sites, thumbnails and gallery images stopped working. Images embedded in the posts and templates were not affected.

Comment: Check your upload folder permission.

Comment: Is the domain name remained? You can check this also: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't getting any error messages even enabling WP Debug and error_reporting(E_ALL), which was the most frustrating part of this.

I traced back through all the layers of Wordpress functions to find the image filters, noticing the names all began 'wp_'. The penny dropped. In migrating, I had to reduce the number of MySQL databases I was using so put my Wordpress DBs together, changing the table prefix.

I changed the prefixes in my SQL export files by doing a bulk find and replace.

This, of course, also updated the data in wp_postmeta, which corresponds to the image filters, to match my new table prefixes, and rendered them broken. A quick SQL update on the wp_postmeta table to remove my table prefixes instantly fixed the problem

Hope this helps others in my situation.

Answer (score -1):

This is permission problem. You need to set permissions to folders 755 and to files 644.

To change all the directories to 755 (-rwxr-xr-x):

```
 find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

To change all the files to 644 (-rw-r--r--):

```
find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: Why down voted? It's potential solution.